# HTML two download link not working together

Tags: html, jquery, json, csv, download

I am trying to make the download link for JSON data converted to CSV.
But two links are not working together. Only one(bottom one) is working.
Do you know why and how to make them work simultaneously?

```js
table.innerHTML += `<tr><td colspan=3><a href ='#' id='ms' download='${username}-${date1}-missing-stress-level.csv'><center>Download Stress ActivityResult</center></td></tr></a>`;
$( "#ms" ).click(function( event ) {
  this.href = 'data:plain/text,' + JSONToCSV(mstl) // Function to convert JSON to CSV
});
                      
var table = document.getElementById('table1');
table.innerHTML += `<a href='#' id='ds' download='${username}-${date1}-daily-survey.csv'><center>Download Daily Survey Result</center></a>`;
$("#ds").click(function( event ) {
  this.href = 'data:plain/text,' + JSONToCSV(ds);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like your structure is wrong:

```
first </a> will close followed by td and tr



table.innerHTML += `<tr><td colspan=3><a href ='#' id='ms' download='${username}-${date1}-missing-stress-level.csv'><center>Download Stress ActivityResult</center></a></td></tr>`;
$( "#ms" ).click(function( event ) {
  this.href = 'data:plain/text,' + JSONToCSV(mstl) // Function to convert JSON to CSV
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It doesn't work either. If I click the first one, it show the code of html, not result. I think the first one can't get the href value..Could you suggest other solution?